# Can we generate a SwiftUI based example project using `pod lib create`?

Tags: ios, swiftui, cocoapods

When I create a new Pod module using `pod lib create <MyLibPod>`, and when it ask the question

```
Would you like to include a demo application with your library? [ Yes / No ]
 > 
yes
```

I use the default as `yes`. It will generate a UIKit based Xcode project. Is there a way to generate a SwiftUI based example project using `pod lib create`?

Comment: I never found any documentation on this....any one can help?

Comment: This might help @xhinoda? https://medium.com/mobile-app-development-publication/modularize-ios-and-android-app-67678f2688dc